# How to setup and use lua squish?

Tags: lua, compilation, squish

I know it can be a dumb question , but how i can setup and use [squish](https://github.com/LuaDist/squish) to compile my lua scripts.
I'm tired searching google and i can't find anything to explain me how to use

Someone can point me on right direction

- I use lua 5.1 on windows OS

Thank you

Comment: There's a README on [squish's homepage](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/squish/home).

Comment: thank you
But my doubt remain.  
They say "just run make"but this is a command line? and if so, how i execute ?
lua squish_floder make ?

Comment: No, there's a standard (Unix) Makefile in the archive. I'll try to translate the commands to Windows in an answer below ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download and unpack the archive containing Squish's code. Alternatively, you may clone [the repository](http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/squish/). The change into the directory containing the `squish.lua` file. You will also need a Lua 5.1 executable (which I'll assume is called `lua51.exe` in the commands below).

The Unix Makefile in the archive contains roughly the following commands (translated to Windows) to build the `squish` tool:

- bootstrap squish tool (without gzip compression or debug support for now)

  ```
  lua51.exe squish.lua -q --with-minify --with-uglify --with-compile --with-virtual-io
  ```
- prepare gzip compression modules

  ```
  lua51.exe squish -q gzip
  ```
- prepare debug support

  ```
  lua51.exe squish -q debug
  ```
- build final tool (with gzip compression and debug support)

  ```
  lua51.exe squish -q --with-minify --with-uglify --with-compile --with-virtual-io --with-gzip --with-debug
  ```

The result is a Lua script `squish` (without the `.lua` extension) in the current directory. To use it you have to write a `squishy` file for your project and execute a command line similar to the last one above in the directory containing your `squishy` file.

Comment: i'm really thankful, just for the record this is what i have done and he worked
i copy the lua.exe (in my case is not lua51).exe  to the squish folder and on CMD i typed full_path_squish + your last line "lua.exe squish -q ....."